# Apple watch minimum requirement to upload on itunesconnect

Tags: ios, watchkit

we had made one application for the apple watch the main thing here is our entire app for watch only means there is nothing to display in the iphone nothing in iphone storyboard just 3 screen in watch so is it fine to submit this in apple or we must have to create something to display in iphone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit standalone Watch apps. There must be a client app to install on the phone. Even if it is just one screen that says "Please use app on your Watch".

Comment: Thanks dude it is the exact answer i was thinking